# Button for `Top Questions` or `Interesting Questions` in header beside Unanswered

Tags: support, feature-request

`Top Questions` view having `Interesting` tab currently opening as landing page or upon clicking Stack Overflow logo.

[image]

So in my opinion to have it as a button beside `Questions` or `Unanswered` button in header area as this feature is also as usable as others present in headers.

Answer (score 2):

There is default features for SO when you will logging default it will show **interesting** tab with questions on the basis of your favorite tags.

You can find this again by clicking on logo of SO. and you will get **interesting** tab and related questions.

This features is for helping you to find the related question in which you are good.

So I don't think there is any need to add an extra tab.

Comment: Thank you @BrokenHeart. Actually i already know what it is and how it comes. I am requesting to make it more usable by providing a prominent instead as it is a helpful feature.

Comment: @AhsanShah I think there is no much space to add a new tab on the panel as can also see.